# fillna in one column only where two other columns are equal from different data frames python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, fillna

I am trying to update my master data table with the information from my custom table.

where mt.type is null update mt.type when mt.item = ct.item

On the internet, I can't find a solution to update one column in a data frame based on a different matched column from the main data frame and another one.

I think maybe I need something like this but with the condition where mt.['item'] matched cc.['item']:

mt['type'] = mt['type'].fillna(cc['type'])

I have also tried using lambda and x and mapper but I can't figure it out.

Tables below:

custom table as ct

| Type | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Cupboard | Pasta |
| Fresh | Apple |
| Frozen | Peas |

master table as mt

| Type | Item | Weather | Shopping Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cupboard | Beans | Sunny | 1 |
| NULL | Pasta | Rainy | NULL |
| NULL | Apples | Null | 2 |
| NULL | Peas | Cloudy | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

desired output

| Type | Item | Weather | Shopping Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cupboard | Beans | Sunny | 1 |
| Cupboard | Pasta | Rainy | NULL |
| Fresh | Apples | Null | 2 |
| Frozen | Peas | Cloudy | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with a little help from [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) :

```
out = mt.assign(Type= mt.set_index("Item")["Type"]
                        .fillna(ct.set_index("Item")["Type"])
                        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

This will create a new `DataFrame`. If you need to overwrite the column `"Type"` in `mt`, use this :

```
mt["Type"] = mt.set_index("Item")["Type"]
                        .fillna(ct.set_index("Item")["Type"])
                        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

​
Output :

```
print(out) # or print(mt)

       Type    Item  Shopping_Week
0     Fresh  Orange            1.0
1     Fresh   Apple            2.0
2     Fresh  Banana            3.0
3  Cupboard     NaN            NaN
4  Cupboard   Beans            4.0
5    Frozen    Peas            7.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This looks great. I'm getting an error though:

FutureWarning: reindexing with a non-unique Index is deprecated and will raise in a future version.

Comment: It means that at least one of the columns `Item` holds duplicates. In case Pasta appears twice in the custom table and with different values (Cupboard, X, Y, ..), what value should be picked to fill the nan in the master table ? Or should we pick all the values as a list ?

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'll try and join on another column also. Thanks again. :)